# URLClassLoader not loading jar file

Tags: java

I'm currently working on an web application, that must load jar files from a directory on the local drive.
After a bit of researching, the `URLClassLoaders` seems to be the best fitting solution.

The beef:

```
public @Slf4j class ActionLoader {
private static void addFilesToClassPath(File path) {
        URLClassLoader clazzLoader = null;
        try {
            clazzLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {path.toURI().toURL()},
                                         ActionLoader.class.getClassLoader());
            try {
                Class.forName("de.befoe.xyz.ActionTest", false, clazzLoader);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                log.error("Class not found", e);
            }
            try {
                clazzLoader.loadClass("de.befoe.xyz.ActionTest");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                log.error("Class not found", e);
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            log.error("Access denied", e);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            log.error("Malformed URL", e);
        } finally {
            if (clazzLoader != null) {
                try {
                    clazzLoader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error("Error closing the class loader", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.befoe.xyz.ActionTest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at de.procrm.speedindexer.scr.ActionLoader.addFilesToClassPath(ActionLoader.java:80)
    at de.procrm.speedindexer.scr.ActionLoader.loadActions(ActionLoader.java:31)
    at de.procrm.speedindexer.scr.Init.contextInitialized(Init.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1612)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1451)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:423)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Second `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.befoe.xyz.ActionTest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at de.procrm.speedindexer.scr.ActionLoader.addFilesToClassPath(ActionLoader.java:81)
    at de.procrm.speedindexer.scr.ActionLoader.loadActions(ActionLoader.java:31)
    at de.procrm.speedindexer.scr.Init.contextInitialized(Init.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1612)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1451)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:423)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The path-variable points to the directory containing the jar files (I also tried initializing the class loader with URLs pointing to the jar files directly).

When I now try to access a class from one of the jar files, I get a `ClassNotFoundException`. When inspecting the class loader in the debugger, I can also see, that the packages- and the classes-fields are both empty, so it doesn't seem as the class loader did load anything.

First I thought it has something to do with missing dependencies, so I created a second jar file with no dependencies and added the classes parent class loader to the constructor, but it changed nothing.

Ideas?

E: After a bit of researching it seems my first thought (dependencies) was correct. I have another library that is used by the web application and the loaded jar files. If I add this library to the the list of jars to add to the URLClassLoader, the jars are loaded just fine. But sure, this is not, what I want to do, because technically my web app uses another class than my jar files, what leads to other problems.

The question now is why the parent class loaders classes are not used properly. After further research it seems the parent class loader I used by calling ActionLoader.class.getClassLoader() was not the correct one. In eclipse debugger therefore I saw a field called delegate which was set to false. So I instead use this class loaders parent, and the files are loading just fine.

Comment: Are you sure that the class is really inside the JAR? Take a look inside the JAR using `jar tf myJar.jar` (where "myJar" is the name of the file you want to load) from the command line.

Comment: As far as I can understand the documentation, the URL should be the jar itself, not the directory containing it. If you pass a directory URL (and you should make sure it ends with a `/` to be considered a directory) then it's probably interpreted as a directory containing the classes directly, as usual in Java.

Comment: After fixing the issue by letting the URL point to the jar file, as @RealSkeptic explained, you should remove the `clazzLoader.close();` invocation, as it is rather unlikely that you are already done using the class you’ve just loaded. Just to avoid the inevitable follow-up question…

Comment: I changed the code back so, that the URLClassLoader ist initialized with the URLs pointing to the files directly, but it still doesn't work.
Removing the clazzLoader.close() still didn't change anything (like I expected, as it is called afterwards).
Both used jar files are fine. I inspected both with "jar tf"-command and all class files are there.

Comment: If you are still having `ClassNotFoundException`s, check if you get any `caused by` in the stack trace. Also, it could be worth it to print the URLs using `getURLs()`, and checking if those URLs are indeed accessible from within the application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your JAR file so i've tested with one of my JAR files on a custom path, and the class is correctly loaded, using the systemClassLoader.

Here is the sample code:

```
addFilesToClassPath(new File("C:/Users/Domenico/.m2/repository/com/doctorchat/core/0.1.ALPHA/core-0.1.ALPHA.jar"));

private static void addFilesToClassPath(File path) {

   try(URLClassLoader clazzLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{path.toURI().toURL()}, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader())) {
            Class c = clazzLoader.loadClass("com.doctorchat.core.exceptions.NotImplementedException");
            System.out.println(c);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //  clazzLoader.getResource()

    }
```

Comment: The reason this succeeds is not because of the System class loader, but because you gave a URL pointing directly to the jar, not to the directory containing it.

Comment: @RealSkeptic As stated above, changing this, didn't work. Using Domenicos approach also did not work, both the classes and the packages of the class loader are still empty.